# Assignment expression in C++ for-loop update expression

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration, variable-assignment

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) the *update expression*, or *iteration expression*, of a *for* cycle in *C++* language can be

> any expression, which is executed after every iteration of the loop and before re-evaluating condition.

Hence, I thought that the following for cycle was correct:

```
//initializations

Point cursor;
cursor.y = minR * pixelSpacing.y + origin.y;
for (int r = minR; r <= maxR; r++, cursor.y += pixelSpacing.y, cursor.x = minC * pixelSpacing.x + origin.x)
{
    //loop statements
}
```

However, the results I obtain at the end of the cycle are different from the ones obtained with the following code:

```
//initializations

Point cursor;
cursor.y = minR * pixelSpacing.y + origin.y;
for (int r = minR; r <= maxR; r++, cursor.y += pixelSpacing.y)
{
    cursor.x = minC * pixelSpacing.x + origin.x;

    //loop statements
}
```

Is it therefore not valid to use an *assignment expression* in an *update expression* of a *for* loop?

Comment: I meant C++, sorry.

Comment: There's no difference between the two examples except for the order when the statements are executed - after or before the loop body. If anything inside the loop depends on these variables, then of course the order matters.

Comment: What are "loop statements"? Do they look up `cursor.x` any time? Or update one of the factors? If you look at the reference, you'll see it's the same as executing it *after* the loop statements, not before. Also, its behavior can be different from just another statement at the end of the loop if you have a `continue` command anywhere in the loop statements. Is that the case?

Comment: in the first example, the assignment is executed AFTER your loop statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
for (int r=minR; r<=maxR; r++, cursor.y += pixelSpacing.y, cursor.x = minC * pixelSpacing.x + origin.x)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
for (int r=minR; r<=maxR; /* nothing here */)
{
  /* loop body here */

  r++;
  cursor.y += pixelSpacing.y; 
  cursor.x = minC * pixelSpacing.x + origin.x;
}
```

So the only difference is the order in which you execute the various statements. Note that the comma operator evaluates left-to-right, where the left-most operand is guaranteed to be executed first.

Comment: except if there is a ``continue`` in the loop body ;^)   (unlikely here)